# Only show one variable label in facet_wrap strip text?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap

I am plotting multiple graphs using `facet_wrap()` from the `ggplot2` package in `R`. When facetting by multiple variables, the result includes both labels in the strip text. How can I remove one?

In this toy example from the `mpg` dataset, how to keep the `cyl` labels only? Thanks

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(c("cyl", "drv"))
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for something like `facet_grid(cyl ~ drv)` instead of `facet_wrap`.

Comment: Alternatively, because I suspect you do not want the empty plots, I would suggest that you create a new columns `cyl_drv` with the appropriate levels and then you can just do `facet_wrap(~cyl_drv)`.

Comment: It doesn't make sense if you use `drv` and then keep only the labels of `cyl`. If you keep `cyl` only, you will have several facets that have label 8.  How can the reader of your plot differentiate between several facets that have the same label?

Comment: Alternatively, you can color the data by drv and keep cyl for facets 

`ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = drv)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~cyl)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The biggest concern with this is as @aelwan mentioned several plots will have the same strip labels but are not the same. Ignoring this issue, I believe the best way to proceed is by creating a new cross variable between `cyl` and `drv`.

So if you just want one row for the strip labels you can for example:

```
ggplot(mpg %>% mutate(cyl_drv = paste0(cyl, '-', drv)), aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ cyl_drv)
```

You can then change the labels if you need as follows:

```
ggplot(mpg %>% mutate(cyl_drv = paste0(cyl, '-', drv)), aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ cyl_drv, labeller = as_labeller(c(`4-4`="4", `4-f`="4", `5-f`=5, `6-4`=6, `6-f`=6, `6-r`=6, `8-4`=8, `8-f`=8, `8-r`=8)))
```

Another (admittedly not great) way to change it is as follows (which I suspect there is a better way to do):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggExtra)
library(grid)
library(gtable)
gg <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ cyl * drv)

g1 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ cyl)

gtab <- ggplotGrob(gg)

gtab$grobs[[47]] <- ggplotGrob(g1)$grobs[[23]]
gtab$grobs[[48]] <- ggplotGrob(g1)$grobs[[23]]
gtab$grobs[[49]] <- ggplotGrob(g1)$grobs[[23]]
gtab$grobs[[50]] <- ggplotGrob(g1)$grobs[[22]]
gtab$grobs[[51]] <- ggplotGrob(g1)$grobs[[22]]
gtab$grobs[[52]] <- ggplotGrob(g1)$grobs[[22]]
gtab$grobs[[53]] <- ggplotGrob(g1)$grobs[[24]]
gtab$grobs[[54]] <- ggplotGrob(g1)$grobs[[24]]
gtab$grobs[[55]] <- ggplotGrob(g1)$grobs[[25]]

grid.draw(gtab)
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Yes I understand the double title issue but have accounted for this with my actual data. Cheers

Comment: Is there a way to do this without manually changing every label? I have 8+ factors (not always the same) in one variable and 2 factors in the other and would like to drop the 2-factor variable from the strip titles as I have a colour aes to handle those.