# Facet grid with two variables but display only one facet label

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using `ggplot2` in order to display some graphics.
I'm using `facet_grid` as in this example:

```
   data(mtcars)
 p<-ggplot(data=mtcars,aes(y=hp,x=wt))+
     geom_point()+facet_grid(cyl+vs ~ .)
```

In my resulting plot I just want to dsplay facet_labels for variable `vs` not for variable `cyl`. How should I do that?

Comment: can't share my data, i rewrite the code with mtcars data

Comment: How exactly do you want the rows labeled then? Do you want to have multiple rows just labeled 0 and 1? That seems kind of unusual.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45114850/only-show-one-variable-label-in-facet-wrap-strip-text