# have labeller express variable name when using data.tables get to construct facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, facet-wrap

when using data.tables `get` function to get data columns from strings when constructing a plot in ggplot2, how to use labeller to get to show the name of the column and its value i.e. `labeller = labeller(.cols = label_both)`  returns `get(facetvar):` and not the content of `facetvar`.

I could construct the labels outside using `as_labeller` (as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45114850/only-show-one-variable-label-in-facet-wrap-strip-text)), however that would be tedious to do completely without hardcoding of either name or values.

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(coverage1 =rep( seq(0,1,0.20),each=4),
                 coverage2 = rep( seq(0,1,0.20),each=4),
                 setting=rep(c('1','2'),each=6),
                 setting2=rep(c('B'),each=12),
                 result=sample(100:1000, 12, replace = FALSE))

xvar='coverage1'
yvar='coverage1'
facetvar = 'setting'
outcomevar = 'result'


ggplot(data=df)+
  geom_point(aes(x=get(xvar), y=get(yvar), size=get(outcomevar)),shape=21)+
  facet_wrap(~get(facetvar), labeller = labeller(.cols = label_both))+
  labs(title = 'funny example plot', subtitle = 'how to get facetvar to show in labels',
  x = xvar, y = yvar, size = outcomevar)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

probably easiest to just create a new column that includes the column name `df$facet_var = paste0(facetvar,':', df[,facetvar])` removing the need to use `labeller` (df needs to be a dataframe)